# Java erased -> compile time type alignment - or Java Library/Framework code transitioning to application logic

Tags: java, generics, java-7, erasure

I am Working on a configuration scenario for a complex distributed OSGi system.

I need to make the following transition from library code to application code on Java 7 (this code below is incorrect):

```
void someFrameworkMethod(...) {
    ....
    // arg 2 is of type Object
    // service is of type SimpleStrongTypedManagedService<?>
    // arg 3 is of type Class<?>
    updateSimple( service, entry.getValue(),  desc.getClazz());
    ....
}

private <T> void updateSimple( SimpleStrongTypedManagedService<T> service,
                               T value,
                               Class<T> clazz) {
        ...
    }
```

I have access to the `clazz` in question. Are there any tricks to get the compiler to "read my mind"(what I am trying to do above) or am I going to have to do reflection / MethodHandle trickery ?

---

I have decided to just store the `MethodHandle` in my library code instead of the `Class<?>` in order to keep going. Still interested in a solution though.

Comment: ...and this worked on Java 6?  I'm looking at this and thinking that `T` would be bound to `Object` if you're telling me that `arg2` was indeed bound to `Object`.

Comment: Could you tell us, which part is yours (and subject to further modifications)? Also, if there are some libs used, can you tell us which ones are those, with a link to their javadoc?

Comment: Both parts are mine no libs are used at this part of the code. I simply need to fiind a way way of calling updateSimple. This is the error : `The method updateSimple(SimpleStrongTypedManagedService<T>, T, Class<T>) in the type ConfigServiceCollection is not applicable for the arguments (SimpleStrongTypedManagedService<capture#12-of ?>, Object, Class<capture#14-of ?>) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is because the method `updateSimple` requires all generic types to be `T`, this means: any but all equal!

However you give different types for the generic parameters, respectively. `?` (any), `Object` and `?` (does not have to be the same as the one before).

So you have two options

1. Drop the requirement that all generic parameters are the same.
2. Cast your parameters so that they are all `<Object>` instead of `<?>`.

Normally casting is a code smell for bad object oriented design, but in case of 3rd party software you sometimes can't avoid it. (and in some other cases the OO complexity to avoid casting is not worth it).

If the parameters you are getting are really of the types you need, then just cast them. Otherwise adapt your method signature so it accepts a more wide range of parameters.

Comment: I was trying to write my helper method to somehow get a hold of a "Type Placeholder" --i.e., `<T>` from the unknown "Type Placeholder" `<?>`.  This is why I thought supplying the ClassTag would help the compiler. So I guess my question would be  how can I cast the interface and the value when all I have is the Class Tag. is  `<?>` a valid "Type Placeholder" to use in casting ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the code in question anymore as I moved to `MethodHandle` which is a better approach anyway as you alluded to . However reading your answer again, Would `<T> void updateSimple(Object iface, Object value, Class<T> clazz);` be the signature I am looking for ? I will be doing a `face.update(value)` right after I have casted both parameters.

Comment: That `updateSimple` signature would indeed allow you to use T to cast the other parameters. Note that for the first parameters you might actually need `SimpleStrongTypedManagedService<?>`.